# *** google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Error opening file: gs://test_documents/uploads/2c4cd57cea679abd7dde9b20023a6c2c.pdf

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-vision

I've seen a similar question posted a couple of times with some suggested steps to resolve that I believe I've followed.  Code is pretty straight out of examples except I am doing everything in one program...load the file to GCS then attempt to process the file using Vision. I set an environment variable at the top that I thought should apply to both functions...file is successfully uploaded to GCS browser and URI confirmed. The permission denied error is puzzling because the credentials have Owner permissions...

Thoughts? This thing dies as soon as the client.async_batch_annotate_files..is invoked

-> operation = client.async_batch_annotate_files(requests=[async_request])
(Pdb) 
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Error opening file: gs://test_documents/uploads/2c4cd57cea679abd7dde9b20023a6c2c.pdf.

```
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud import storage
from google.protobuf import json_format
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]=config.gstorage
mime_type = 'application/pdf'
batch_size = 2

doc = DocumentMaster.objects.get(document_id=14)
bname = 'test_documents'
fname = doc.document_hash_key+".pdf"
in_target = os.path.join("uploads",fname)
out_target = os.path.join("document_json",fname)

fullpath = os.path.join(bname,in_target)
fullpath2 = os.path.join(bname,out_target)
private_in = "gs://"+fullpath
private_out = "gs://test_documents/document_json"

CloudStorage = storage.Client()
StorageBucket = CloudStorage.get_bucket(bname)
blob = StorageBucket.blob(in_target)
blob.upload_from_filename(doc.document_original.path)

client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

feature = vision.types.Feature(type=vision.enums.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION)

gcs_source = vision.types.GcsSource(uri=private_in)
input_config = vision.types.InputConfig(gcs_source=gcs_source, mime_type=mime_type)
gcs_destination = vision.types.GcsDestination(uri=private_out)
output_config = vision.types.OutputConfig(gcs_destination=gcs_destination, batch_size=batch_size)

async_request = vision.types.AsyncAnnotateFileRequest(features=[feature], input_config=input_config,output_config=output_config)

operation = client.async_batch_annotate_files(requests=[async_request])
print('Waiting for the operation to finish.')
operation.result(timeout=30)
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I underestimated how particular admin was in GCS cloud storage. While project has service account, it also needed to be explicitly permissioned to retrieve the files it had just uploaded...closing